# Как сделать редирект с браузера в мобильное приложение без блокировки?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cordova, quasar.js

Задача стоит такая: есть мобильное приложение в котором совершается редирект в браузер. В браузере юзер нажимает еще одну кнопку и переходит дальше в другую страницу браузера. Как только он перейдет на вторую страницу в браузере, мне надо по истечении нескольких секунд автоматически вернуть юзера в мобилку. Мое решение: т.к приложение билдится с Cordova, использовала плагин [cordova-plugin-customurlscheme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-customurlscheme). Создалась android scheme = 'mycoolapp', настроила AndroidManifest и др. согласно документации. Все работает. Проблема: когда я делаю ссылку
 `<a href="mycoolapp://"> Open my app </a>` 
и юзер кликает на нее приложение открывается без проблем. Но мне нужно автоматический редирект без участия юзера. Попробовала так:

`mounted: function () {
    window.open('mycoolapp://', '_system')
  }`

здесь открывает в всплывающем окне и просит юзера подтвердить открытие. Иначе блокирует. Понятно, что браузер видит это как спам. Можете подсказать альтернативные варианты? Или же может я вообще не так делаю?